# Python List to a Django Databse Table

Tags: python, django

I have some Django fields, and here is what i'm trying to do.

I have a `Times` field, a `Price` Field and a `Start Date` field.

So the User would input, for example:

```
Times = 12

Price = 100,00

Start Date = 2019-11-01
```

with those, the following lists are created:

```
Times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Price = [100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, 100,00, ]

Start Date = [2019-11-01, 2019-12-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-04-01, 2020-05-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-08-01, 2020-09-01, 2020-10-01, 2020-11-01]
```

I already know how to create those lists, i'm struggling on how to insert them into Django's Database Table, one per line with the same ID or PK.
Example -

Times Price Dates

```
1  100,00 2019-11-01

2  100,00 2019-12-01.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct these objects in a list, and then make a query to insert these in bulk, like:

```
MyModel.objects.bulk_create([
    MyModel(time=time, price=price, start_date=start_date)
    for time, price, start_date in zip(list_of_time, list_of_price, list_of_date)
])
```

If the number of objects is large, then creating these in "bulk" at the database side will result in a significant speedup.

Comment: Thank you. It Works! However it's adding one new ID to each line in the Database. Is there a way for it to have the same ID, for each query?  In my example above, the 12 lines would have the same ID, and etc....

Comment: @M.creations: two objects can not have the same id. A primary key is guaranteed to be unique. This is necessary to make an unambiguous reference to an object.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: renamed variables for better understanding

```
for t, p, sd in zip(times, prices, start_dates):
    YourModel.objects.create(Times=t, Price=p, StartDate=sd)
```